# ADB in Android Studio sees device as offline

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, usb-debugging

After connecting my galaxy s7 ADB sees device ok for about 500 ms. In that short time logcat wrote out lots of text which immediately disappeared. After that it is marked as `[OFFLINE]`. I have tried restarting android studio, phone, USB debugging, ADB server and reinstalled SDK. I have allowed USB debugging authorization for PC.

PC OS: Win 10

Android: 7.0

Do you have any idea what to do about it ?

Comment: Reinstalling drivers may help.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, I have tried uninstalling Androidstudio, changing cable, installing other drivers but ADB driver is not installing, but still shows offline.Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change USB cable. Your current USB cable's data transfer speed is slow that's why it is detecting but showing OFFLINE.

Comment: I kept my current cable, but connected it to usb 3.0 port instead of 2.0. That helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try another cable. I had this issue when I used cheap usb cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any issues with the cable, then try to change it.

1. Try to install required driver.
2. Use ADB command from the android
   studio teminal

   `adb tcpip <port>`
   `adb connect <ip>:<port>`